# How to replace a specific datetime value with NULL in MySQL column?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, replace, null

Not being an SQL expert, I am having trouble with a simple replacement of a specific date-time value with NULL in MySQL. The nullable `last_login DATETIME` column in question may have values of '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' as a result of populating rows from an Excel spreadsheet which do not have that date (i.e. empty cells). Each database row is uniquely identified by an `id INT` column. I tried:

```
UPDATE user_profiles
SET last_login = NULL
WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM user_profiles WHERE last_login = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000');
```

But MySQL (and I suspect other databases as well) protests that the WHERE clause applies to the same column as the one being updated. What is the solution?

Comment: why not simply `update user_profiles set last_login = NULL where last_login = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use a sub query in your where statement:

```
UPDATE user_profiles
SET last_login = NULL
WHERE last_login = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000';
```

Comment: This works fine. I was clearly over-complicating the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a sub-query with the same fields, you'll need to identify the tables. Either by using the table names or by giving them an alias. So using your code, this should work:

```
UPDATE user_profiles u
SET u.last_login = NULL
WHERE u.id IN
(SELECT x.id FROM user_profiles x WHERE x.last_login = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000');
```

That being said, like most people are saying, you don't need to use a subquery:

```
UPDATE user_profiles
SET last_login = NULL
WHERE last_login = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000';
```